# Spring Boot - Override injected implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new in Spring Boot and I'm I'm facing the following :

```
public interface A {}

public class AImpl implements A {}

public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
 private A a;

 @Autowired
 public MyClassImpl(A a) {
      this.a = a;
 } 
}
```

And `MyClass` is being autowired in another class.

At launch, my program is going through `MyClassImpl`'s constructor with parameter a being an `AImpl`.

But now, I would like a class, let's say `A2Impl` to implement interface `A` too, and be the implementation used in `MyClassImpl`'s constructor instead.

A and `AImpl` come from a library. I wrote this `A2Impl` class but there is no change, not even an error indicating that `SB` doesn't know which implementation to use... It just still use `AImpl`...

What am I missing...?

Comment: Is your `A2Impl` marked with the appropriate `@Component` annotation? If not, how is it added to the Spring context? How is the original `AImpl` added to the Spring context? Your example isn't complete enough for us to help you.

Comment: Is it the same if I put @Service ? Didn't do it because I didn't see it on the library's classes either (A and AImpl)...

Comment: @Nyaw, it's not the same, but it's going to work

Comment: It's a stereotype annotation of `@Component`, so yes, it should work. Could you update your question with some more specific code? Preferably a minimal example that reproduces the issue you're having. It's probably related to your component scanning packages (i.e. which packages inside your JAR are being loaded by Spring's component scanning utility) or any XML or config beans that are in your app.

Comment: I actually found it was coming from some auto configuration of Spring Boot that loaded AImpl as defaut implementation of A !